# How to get access to WebRTC RTP packet sequence number

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtp

In WebRTC, each RTP packet will have a sequence number in the header. (See here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/real-time-transport-protocol-rtp/ )

But is there a way to access this raw sequence number from the web? I've been looking into transform streams and videoframes but haven't seen an interface that exposes it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to access raw RTP packets in browser. Packetization, jitter buffer, congestion control and other low-level streaming protocol features are hidden in WebRTC implementation.

There are ways to access individual video frames though if you interested in modifying them. See [insertable streams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Insertable_Streams_for_MediaStreamTrack_API) (for decoded frames) or [RTCRtpScriptTransform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpScriptTransform/RTCRtpScriptTransform#options) (for encoded frames).

Comment: Thanks for responding. I was afraid this was the case. Do you have any supporting documentation for this? or are you just going off of the absence of any documentation for getting the packet?

Comment: I just realized you answered my question yesterday too! Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Yeah, I'm judging based on the absence of this feature in w3c specifications, searched for it thoroughly myself. Looks like web APIs for WebRTC are intentionally high level, leaving more freedom for underlying implementations